# No message recieved from pcl/NormalEstimation nodelet

Tags: rviz, openni, pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to run simple example with kinect and normal estimation, I'm running a simple launch file:

```
<launch>
<!-- Launch openni grabber -->
<include file="$(find openni_launch)/launch/openni.launch"/>

<!-- Launch nodelet manager -->
<node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="nodelet_manager"  args="manager" output="screen"/>

<!-- Normal Estimation -->
<node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="normal_estimation" args="load pcl/NormalEstimation nodelet_manager" output="screen">
    <remap from="~input" to="/camera/depth_registered/points"/>
    <rosparam>
        # -[ Mandatory parameters
        k_search: 0
        radius_search: 0.015
        spatial_locator: 0
    </rosparam>

</node>
</launch>
```

but I'm getting "No message received" if I try to subscribe /normal_estimation/output topic in rviz, even though `rostopic echo /normal_estimation/output` show that messages are published.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33189/no-message-recieved-from-pcl/normalestimation-nodelet/) by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 801 on 2012-05-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-05-03**:
can you please share the screenshot of the rxgraph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I thing that the problem is that pcl/NormalEstimation publishes pcl::Normal, which does not contain coordinates.

---

Originally posted by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) with karma: 801 on 2012-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1